# creating object according to the switch case value

Tags: actionscript-3

i have the following switch case:

```
    switch (appModel.currentPage){
                case "Programma":
                case "Winkelwagen":
                case "Films":
                case "Contact":
                    if (page){
                        removeChild(page);
                    }
    //here i would like to create a new object page that has the type of the switch.
i mean this: var page: getDefinitionByName(appModel.currentPage+"Page");

this doesnt work thou but it should be something like: "FilmsPage or ContactPage or ...".
                    addChild(page);
                    break;
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var pageClass:Object = getDefinitionByName(appModel.currentPage+"Page");
var page:DisplayObject = new pageClass();
addChild( page );
```

Comment: Ok ive done what you said, i just added the package of tha pages in front of the appmodel. I do get an error. error 1065 -> variable WinkelwagenPage not defined. the classname is correct and the package is correct aswell. He throws that error on de first line of the code you supplied

Answer (score 0):

PatrickS's answer should work, but you will need to make sure all the classes that you will use are referenced somewhere, or the compiler will skip over them, and not add them to your SWF.